# Wordpress ajax-admin.php waiting time too long

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, loading, admin-ajax

My wordpress admin dashboard is loading slowly and taking too much time to load. The wordpress homepage loading time is okay. But when I logged in, and move to admin dashboard, all activities loaded slowly (up to 35s).

I have view network console, and see that `admin-ajax.php` waiting time is very very long. Try to search and follow some advice in google. Use P3 plugin but not found any thing. Disable heartbeat, use cache, etc. Tried disable all plugins too. But it's no happen. So how can I solve this problem?

This is my server information: https://thefoxyeden.com/infophp.php

Comment: you are going to need to provide a lot more information; have you even checked your mysql transactions?

Comment: @Napoli not yet, which I need to check more?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was from the wp_users table that had around 160580 users, when reduced them to 1000 the loading time reduced drastically.